# Pandas DF convert date string to date year and month

Tags: python, pandas

HI all I have a column in a dataframe that looks like:

```
print(df['Date']):

29-Nov-16
4-Dec-16
1-Oct-16
30-Nov-19
30-Jun-20
28-Apr-16
24-May-16
```

And i am trying to get an output that looks like

```
print(df):
Date            Month          Year
29-Nov-16       Nov             2016
4-Dec-16       Dec             2016
1-Oct-16       Oct             2016
30-Nov-19       Nov             2019
30-Jun-20       Jun             2020
28-Apr-16       Apr             2016
24-May-16       May             2016
```

I have tried the following:

```
df['Month'] = pd.datetime(df['Date']).month
df['Year'] = pd.datetime(df['Date']).year
```

but am getting a `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

Any ideas or references to help out?
Thanks!

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.month` and same for year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `dt` after `pd.datetime(df['Date'])`

try this:

```
df['Month'] = pd.datetime(df['Date']).dt.month
df['Year'] = pd.datetime(df['Date']).dt.year
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `strftime` and `str.split` and assign them to new columns

```
df_final = df.assign(**pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
                                                 .str.split('-', expand=True)
                                                 .set_axis(['Month','Year'], axis=1))

Out[32]:
        Date Month  Year
0  29-Nov-16   Nov  2016
1   4-Dec-16   Dec  2016
2   1-Oct-16   Oct  2016
3  30-Nov-19   Nov  2019
4  30-Jun-20   Jun  2020
5  28-Apr-16   Apr  2016
6  24-May-16   May  2016
```